# Writing code that can be compiled on both linux and windows

Tags: c, linux, windows

I am looking to create a project that will be handling files. It will open, write and repeat for an entire directory.

My question is, can I make this in one project but compile on the two different machines (Windows and Linux)? Or is it easier to just write a Windows project and then write a different project for Linux?

I was just trying to eliminate to need to change code twice.

Comment: There are frameworks to give you common calls, such as .NET on Linux, or mingw on Windows.  Without those, native calls are very different.

Comment: Afaik, C doesn't have a stadardized way to "open" a directory to check what files there are in that directory. You could create some wrapper functions around the platform specific parts though and then in the bulk of the code you could stick with standard C.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that but then I start to get into a lot of ifdefs and I feel like it would get a bit confusing.

Comment: @xx9000 I usually put the platform specific parts in a `struct` that I call something nice, like `typedef struct { ... } dir_handle_t;` In a header file for Windows, the struct will be defined containing a `HANDLE` and a `WIN32_FIND_DATA`. On Linux it could be a `DIR*`. In the corresponding `.c` files for those platforms, there will be functions (with the same names) that takes one of these `dir_handle_t*` as argument and "does something" (similar on both platforms) with it.

Comment: The bulk of the code will only use `dir_handle_t`s and whatever the functions called returns. When you compile for Windows, the Windows parts of this setup will be included and on Linux, the linux parts. No `#ifdef`s anywhere.

Comment: The only tricky part is to come up with a good interface that works on both platforms so you must know what limitations both have before starting to code (too much).